# 301 Redirect placing original URL in querystring to new page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm completely baffled and could use help writing rules for a specific redirect pattern.

In the original site the URL might be something like:

https://subdomain.originalsite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.tt?state=CA&lvl=state

or

https://subdomain.originalsite.com/folder1/folder2/?command=state_search&state=CA

or any number of similar requests

When this redirects I need it landing on http://newsite.com/newfile.php regardless of the original URL, but I need the new page to be "fed" the original URL so we can do some processing based on the original URL

Is there any way to pass the original URL in querystring data to the new one?

The end result for the two examples being:

http://newsite.com/newfile.php?path=folder1/folder2/folder3/file.tt&q=state|CA||lvl=state

and

http://newsite.com/newfile.php?path=folder1/folder2/&q=command|state_search||state|CA

so what had been the folder path on original becomes path= and what started the querystring (if any) on the original becomes q=

the original querystring key/value pairs replace = with a pipe|  and ampersand becomes double pipe ||

I realize this is ugly.

Any help in writing this rule deeply appreciated.

Comment: It will be lot better (and cleaner) to have new URL as `http://newsite.com/newfile.php?path=folder1/folder2/&q=<encoded original query string>`

Comment: that would be great but I still need to understand the rule to make that happen

Comment: Of course something like this should be possible … but have you _tried_ anything …?

Comment: If I understood I would not have asked. I find the rewrite rules vexing at best and have spent quite a few hours reading to try and understand how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `subdomain.originalsite.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.originalsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com?path=%{REQUEST_URI}&q=%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R]
```